# Password login in python command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting to learn python and faced with such a problem, I have main.py I want all the functionality in it to work with a password that will be taken from a text document on the site.

See here is the code

```
            from selenium import webdriver
            from os import system, name

            from time import time, strftime, gmtime, sleep
            import pyfiglet, os, threading
            import webbrowser

            def clear():
                if name == 'nt':
                    _ = system('cls')
                else:
                    _ = system('clear')

            clear()
            system('title TUT.GURU')

            print(pyfiglet.figlet_format("TUT.GURU", font="slant"))
            print("1. Viewbot.\n2. Heartbot.\n3. Followerbot.\n3. Sharebot.\n4. Credits.\n5. Инфо\n\nЗакажите сайт или программу у меня в ТГ: @whitehak\nЗаходи к нам на форум: TUT.GURU\n\n")

            auto = int(input("Режим: "))

            if auto == 1 or auto == 2 or auto == 3 or auto == 4:
                vidUrl = input("Вставьте ссылку на видео: ")

                start = time()
                time_elapsed = strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(time() - start))

                chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
                chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

                driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
                driver.set_window_size(425, 948)
                

                Views = 0
                Hearts = 0
                Followers = 0

            def beautify(arg):
                return format(arg, ',d').replace(',', '.')

            def title1(): # Update the title IF option 1 was picked.
                global Views
                
                while True:
                    time_elapsed = strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(time() - start))
                    system(f'title TUT.GURU ^| Views Sent: {beautify(Views)} ^| Программа работает: {time_elapsed}')

            def title2(): # Update the title IF option 2 was picked.
                global Hearts
                
                while True:
                    time_elapsed = strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(time() - start))
                    system(f'title TUT.GURU ^| Hearts Sent: {beautify(Hearts)} ^| Программа работает: {time_elapsed}')

            def title3(): # Update the title IF option 3 was picked.
                global Followers
                
                while True:
                    time_elapsed = strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(time() - start))
                    system(f'title TUT.GURU ^| Followers Sent: {beautify(Followers)} ^| Программа работает: {time_elapsed}')
                    
            def title4(): # Update the title IF option 1 was picked.
                global Shares
                
                while True:
                    time_elapsed = strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(time() - start))
                    system(f'title TUT.GURU ^| Shares Sent: {beautify(Shares)} ^| Программа работает: {time_elapsed}')

                
            def loop1():
                global Views
                sleep(10)
                
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/button").click()
                    
                except:
                    print("[-] Капча не разгадана!")
                    driver.refresh()
                    loop1()
                    
                try:
                    sleep(2)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sid4\"]/div/form/div/input").send_keys(vidUrl)
                    
                    sleep(1)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sid4\"]/div/form/div/div/button").click()
                    
                    sleep(5)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"c2VuZC9mb2xsb3dlcnNfdGlrdG9V\"]/div[1]/div/form/button").click()
                    
                    driver.refresh()
                    Views += 1000
                    print("[+] Views sended!")
                    
                    sleep(300)
                    loop1()
                    
                except:
                    print("[-] Пробуем еще раз") 
                    driver.refresh()
                    loop1()

            def loop2():
                global Hearts
                sleep(10)
                
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/button").click()
                    
                except:
                    print("[-] Капча не разгадана!")
                    driver.refresh()
                    loop2()
                    
                try:
                    sleep(2)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sid2"]/div/form/div/input').send_keys(vidUrl)
                    
                    sleep(1)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sid2"]/div/form/div/div/button').click()
                    
                    sleep(5)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c2VuZE9nb2xsb3dlcnNfdGlrdG9r"]/div[1]/div/form/button').click()
                    
                    sleep(6)
                    hearts = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c2VuZE9nb2xsb3dlcnNfdGlrdG9r"]/span').text.split()
                    
                    Hearts += int(hearts[0])
                    print("[+] Hearts sended!")
                    
                    sleep(5)
                    driver.refresh()
                    
                    sleep(1800)
                    loop2()
                    
                except:
                    print("[-] Пробуем еще раз") 
                    driver.refresh()
                    loop2()

            def loop3():
                global Followers
                sleep(10)
                
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/button").click()
                    
                except:
                    print("[-] Капча не разгадана!")
                    driver.refresh()
                    loop3()
                    
                try:
                    sleep(2)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sid\"]/div/form/div/input").send_keys(vidUrl)
                    
                    sleep(1)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sid\"]/div/form/div/div/button").click()
                    
                    sleep(5)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"c2VuZF9mb2xsb3dlcnNfdGlrdG9r\"]/div[1]/div/form/button").click()
                    sleep(6)
                    folls = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c2VuZF9mb2xsb3dlcnNfdGlrdG9r"]/span').text.split()
                    
                    Followers += int(folls[0])
                    print("[+] Followers sended!")
                    driver.refresh()
                    
                    sleep(1800)
                    loop3()
                    
                except:
                    print("[-] Пробуем еще раз")
                    driver.refresh()
                    loop3()

            def loop4():
                global Shares
                sleep(10)
                
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/button").click()
                    
                except:
                    print("[-] Капча не разгадана!")
                    driver.refresh()
                    loop4()
                    
                try:
                    sleep(2)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sid7\"]/div/form/div/input").send_keys(vidUrl)
                    
                    sleep(1)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sid7\"]/div/form/div/div/button").click()
                    
                    sleep(5)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"c2VuZC9mb2xsb3dlcnNfdGlrdG9s\"]/div[1]/div/form/button").click()
                    
                    driver.refresh()
                    Shares += 100
                    print("[+] Shares sended!")
                    
                    sleep(300)
                    loop4()
                    
                except:
                    print("[-] Пробуем еще раз")
                    driver.refresh()
                    loop4()

            clear()
```

you need to ask for a password when you turn on the program and if it is correct, then run the program and if not, then write that the password is not correct.
The password will be stored on the website
example: domen.com/pass.txt

I can't figure out how to do this

Comment: *This is a bad idea!* It may not seem like people will figure out the "magic", but they will. Any clown with a web browser can go to pages like that, even if you don't intend them to. And in your case it's even worse. You're writing in Python, which means whoever is running your code has access to the source code and can *see* where the password is stored. You can hide it a bit with a `.pyc` file, but *only* a bit. The tool `strings`, which comes *built-in* to Linux, is capable of finding string constants like your super-secret password URL in a file like a `pyc` file. *It is a very bad idea.*

Answer (score 0):

I would just not do that. Why would you ever *want* to give away your plaintext password to every man, woman, and child in the world with Internet access to `domain.com`?

That said, if you want to fetch a file via URL, check out the [`requests` library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

```py
requests.get('https://example.com/file.png')
```